# Using Laravel Livewire's #[Validate] on nullable fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel Livewire's `#[Validate]` on a nullable field, and I only want to validate the field as an integer.

```
...
#[Validate('integer', message: 'Asking price must be an integer.')]
public $business_asking_price;
...
```

The code above works to ensure the user enters only integers but doesn't allow the field to remain null.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nullable`:

```php
#[Validate('integer|nullable', message: 'Asking price must be an integer.')]
public $business_asking_price;
```

Comment: adding nullable didn't work

Answer (score 0):

When saving the field with no value previously added, I didn't get the error, it was only when I deleted the value and tried to save the form is when I saw the error.  When deleting the current value, `""` was saved in its place and it errored out.  All I did to fix it was make sure Null was added to the field with `'business_asking_price' => $this->business_asking_price ?? Null,`.